# Prolog ... define predicate that checks if both arguments are/point to the same atom

Tags: prolog

I have a prolog predicate that takes two parameters (both labelled `X` here since they should be the same) and compares them to see if they evaluate to the same atom. That is the intent. However, the predicate unexpectedly returns false when both arguments are variables.

I'm trying to define a notion of an expression in sentential logic / propositional calculus being in "implication normal form" in Prolog. Implication normal form here meaning that all connectives are replaced with `->` and `falsum`.

As a base case, I want to say that an expression consisting entirely of an atom is already in normal form with itself.

Here's how I'm attempting to express that. I'm repeating a parameter name instead of doing some type of check of sameness between the parameters.

```
% foo.P
implication_normal(X, X) :- atom(X).
```

This incomplete-but-still-useful definition is intended to capture the fact that `implication_normal(x, x)` is true but `implication_normal(x, y)` is false.

In some ways it seems to work:

```
$ swipl -s foo.P

?- implication_normal(x, x).
true.

?- implication_normal(x, y).
false.

?- implication_normal(1, 1).
false.
```

It does the wrong thing with variables (It should be enumerating pairs of "binding contexts" where `X` and `Z` happen to point to the same atom).

```
?- implication_normal(X, Z).
false.
```

It also just returns false if you give it the same variable twice.

```
?- implication_normal(X, X).
false.
```

for some strange reason, the behavior is correct if you give it a variable and a single atom (and you get failure with an integer).

```
?- implication_normal(X, z).
X = z.

?- implication_normal(X, 1).
false.
```

and similarly if the variable is second.

```
?- implication_normal(z, X).
X = z.

?- implication_normal(1, X).
false.
```

How do I change the definition of `implication_normal` so that it enumerates in all the cases where variables are supplied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard `atom/1` predicate is a **type-checking** predicate. It doesn't enumerate atoms. It just deterministically checks if its argument is an atom. Moreover, your definition of the `implication_normal /2` predicate attempts to **unify** its two arguments and, if the unification is successful, calls `atom/1` with the resulting term. That's why a call such as `implication_normal(X, z)` succeeds: `X` is unified with `z` and `atom(z)` is true.

Note that some Prolog systems provide a `current_atom/1` that does enumerate atoms. On those systems, you could write instead:

```
implication_normal(X, X) :- current_atom(X).
```

Some sample calls using SWI-Prolog:

```
?- implication_normal(X, Z).
X = Z, Z = '' ;
X = Z, Z = abort ;
X = Z, Z = '$aborted'
...

?- implication_normal(X, X).
X = '' ;
X = abort ;
X = '$aborted' ;
...

?- implication_normal(X, z).
X = z.

?- implication_normal(X, 1).
false.
```

Comment: So, I did try  `imp_norm(X, Z) :- p_variable(x), p_variable(Z), X = Z.` and that appeared to work.  Is there any difference between using, say, `imp_norm(X, X) :- current_atom(X)` and `imp_norm(X, Z) :- current_atom(X), current_atom(Z), X = Z`?

Comment: The first will be faster than the second.